# Uber Ride Reminders API does not responds always

Tags: uber-api

We have properly implemented the Uber Ride Reminder API and we are getting the expected results when requested.

The only issue we are facing is, out of 100+ requests we get the response for any one of those request. Rest of the requests simply responds with empty response.

We are using Following Function to make Curl Post request:

```
function get_data_post($url, $post_data, $headers = false, $timeout = 3) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = $timeout;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    if($headers) 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

And here are the input parameters:

URL: https://api.uber.com/v1/reminders

Request Object: 
{"reminder_time":1469880000,"phone_number":"+911231231234","event":{"time":1469894400,"name":"DIY Artistic Frames","location":"pH Designs","latitude":"23.03743","longitude":"72.5682099"}}

Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token xyxxyxxyx-Aux

Comment: Could you provide an HTTP trace of the request/response of the successful and unsuccessful calls?

Comment: Update in the question. Please chcek now.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm that you really don't get a response by using curl? I tried the same exact request I got a response. Here's the curl command (replace the token): `curl -X "POST" "https://api.uber.com/v1/reminders" \
 -H "Authorization: Token {TOKEN}" \
 -H "Content-type: application/json" \
 -d "{\"reminder_time\":1470103623,\"phone_number\":\"+911231231234\",\"event\":{\"time\":1470103623,\"name\":\"DIY Artistic Frames\",\"location\":\"pH Designs\",\"latitude\":\"23.03743\",\"longitude\":\"72.5682099\"}}"`

Comment: I tried with Curl from server. And it is working. Event with PHP API it's working fine. The issue is, it returns blank response for some of the calls.

Comment: Could you please also guide me how can I pass our referral code in this API so if the user is not registered on Uber, they can get our Referral code in SMS notification.

Comment: By default, the Ride Reminders API is rate limited to 10 requests per hour. You're probably getting rate limited if you're trying to perform hundreds of requests. Does your use case require this high volume of requests?

Comment: If so, can you provide your app's client ID and we can whitelist you for a higher volume?

Comment: Hi @Alec, at any time we have around 500 people active. We can not go live with 10 request per hour. Our App's client ID is itnnxil6NkDyualpxwkTvNdVN5HmsLwj

Also let us know how to add our Promo code to SMS which Uber sents to non uber users.

Comment: We whitelisted itnnxil6NkDyualpxwkTvNdVN5HmsLwj. Unfortunately, there's no way to specify a custom promo code for the SMS messages at the moment.

Comment: Since the Ride Reminders API doesn't currently support putting custom promo codes in the SMS, the best option (for now) is to have messaging in your website or app that encourages users to enter your custom promo code manually.